# Phonegap Android Geolocation watchPosition timeout

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I am using Cordova 3.0.0, A Samsung Galaxy S3 4.1.2 to test.

When I test the Phonegap full example for watching position : http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/cordova_geolocation_geolocation.md.html#geolocation.watchPosition

I get one first line with coords, and then I got the error :

```
code 3
message : Position retrieval timed out.
```

And no other location are returned. The same code on my iphone is working.
I am testing when walking, and when I was in a car, same thing.

I noticed that when I use google maps on the android device, a gps icons pops up on the top bar.
When I launch my app, it is not here.

The Manifest is correctly set up with permissions, and my options are :

```
var options = { maximumAge: 3000, timeout: 5000, enableHighAccuracy: true };
watchID = navigator.geolocation.watchPosition( onSuccess, onError, options );
```

I need precision for my app to work...

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Ok, so after hours of tests, I managed to make the watchPosition work on Android with Cordova 3.1.0 .

What you have to do: Use the html5 only api for geolocation and do not include this : http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.1.0/cordova_geolocation_geolocation.md.html#Geolocation

If you already have it in your projet, remove it via the CLI : 
    cordova plugin rm org.apache.cordova.geolocation

Of course, keep those lines in your android  manifest :

```
< uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
< uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
< uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS" />
```

This is working for me, so tell me if its working for you. I will post code if you need ( but the cordova full example works for example )

Comment: Removing the plugin fixes the issue. It still seems a bit unstable with my app, I often still get timeouts but it could be caused by AJAX calls happening in the background at the same time.
Thanks though!

Comment: was having this problem with Cordova 3.1 iOS7 and this also fixed the issue

Comment: @arlg Yes, this fixes the problem for me on Android with Cordova 3.1.0. Nice find.

Comment: hi @arlg - quite new to this, please could you confirm i've done this ok... added `xmlns:android = "http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"` to config.xml `widget` and created an `AndroidManifest.xml` in app root with those three `<uses-permission>` lines. The app i'm testing I uploaded using the phonegap build upload function. how do you remove the corova geolocation?

Comment: Here is an official reference to what you say http://markmail.org/message/ketdgrzm2dcpxfo2#query:+page:1+mid:ketdgrzm2dcpxfo2+state:results

Answer (score 3):

Maybe this can help you :

I just discover one massive problem in Cordova/PhoneGap : - When you open the Android project built by cordova (in commandline), the requestUpdate is set at ..... 60 Seconds !!!!!!!!!!! You have a new Location every Minute ! Evenif you use GPS (enableHighAccuracy="true"). So try to set this at 1000 where you find LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER in org.apache.cordova.geolocation package -> GPSListener class !

Comment: This is true. I get a position every 60 seconds! Does not matter timeout nor maximumAge

Comment: So you have open the android project with Eclipse ?

Comment: No, I'm using cordova-cli, but it's the same problem. I found this http://markmail.org/message/ketdgrzm2dcpxfo2#query:+page:1+mid:ketdgrzm2dcpxfo2+state:results the developers say that you should not use anymore the geolocation plugin.

Comment: Oh god. Thanks for the link. When I think my boss wanted to create a Sport Tracking App with cordova...

Comment: Thanks for the link too. Hopefully they will rewrite all the Geolocation plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you're right, there appears to be a problem with geolocation in Phonegap v3.x - I have 3.1.0-0.15.0 installed. I'm seeing the same: a single correct position, then a timeout error, triggering the clear/re-add of the watcher, followed by a correct position. Running the same test app on Phonegap 2.9.0, it works fine, successfully retrieving positions. This time I used the options `{ maximumAge: 0, timeout: 30000, enableHighAccuracy: true };`

See if you get the same results: [here's the v3.1.0 project&APK](http://ge.tt/6AXk1Bw/v/0) and [here's the v2.9.0 project&APK](http://ge.tt/3xgS1Bw/v/0).

Here's the logcat when I built it with Phonegap 3.1.0:

```
10-24 20:50:29.287: I/Web Console(17092): Device Ready at :1171167449
10-24 20:50:59.287: I/Web Console(17092): Error while retrieving current position. Error code: 3,Message: Position retrieval timed out. at :1171167509
10-24 20:51:29.328: I/Web Console(17092): Error while retrieving current position. Error code: 3,Message: Position retrieval timed out. at :1171167509
10-24 20:51:59.337: I/Web Console(17092): Error while retrieving current position. Error code: 3,Message: Position retrieval timed out. at :1171167445
10-24 20:52:28.397: I/Web Console(17092): Position updated: latitude=50.64626501666667, longitude=-4.736916616666666, accuracy=17m at :-1468095491
10-24 20:52:28.397: I/Web Console(17092): Position updated: latitude=50.64626501666667, longitude=-4.736916616666666, accuracy=17m at :-1468095491
10-24 20:52:58.407: I/Web Console(17092): Error while retrieving current position. Error code: 3,Message: Position retrieval timed out. at :1171167445
10-24 20:53:27.878: I/Web Console(17092): Position updated: latitude=50.646433849999994, longitude=-4.736890766666666, accuracy=8m at :-1468095491
10-24 20:53:27.878: I/Web Console(17092): Position updated: latitude=50.646433849999994, longitude=-4.736890766666666, accuracy=8m at :-1468095491
10-24 20:53:57.887: I/Web Console(17092): Error while retrieving current position. Error code: 3,Message: Position retrieval timed out. at :1171167445
10-24 20:54:27.367: I/Web Console(17092): Position updated: latitude=50.64643435, longitude=-4.736896850000001, accuracy=9m at :-1468095491
10-24 20:54:27.367: I/Web Console(17092): Position updated: latitude=50.64643435, longitude=-4.736896850000001, accuracy=9m at :-1468095491
10-24 20:54:57.377: I/Web Console(17092): Error while retrieving current position. Error code: 3,Message: Position retrieval timed out. at :1171167445
```

And here's the logcat from exactly the same app when I built it using Phonegap v2.9.0:

```
10-24 21:10:19.698: I/Web Console(19755): Device Ready at :1172318425
10-24 21:10:22.487: I/Web Console(19755): Position update rejected because accuracy of45m is less than required 20m at :1172318349
10-24 21:10:54.697: I/Web Console(19755): Position updated: latitude=50.646209633333335, longitude=-4.737049566666667, accuracy=9m at :1172318421
10-24 21:10:55.177: I/Web Console(19755): Position updated: latitude=50.64623646666667, longitude=-4.7369963, accuracy=9m at :1172318421
10-24 21:10:56.177: I/Web Console(19755): Position updated: latitude=50.64623674999999, longitude=-4.736949983333333, accuracy=9m at :1172318357
10-24 21:10:57.677: I/Web Console(19755): Position updated: latitude=50.646237033333335, longitude=-4.73695015, accuracy=9m at :1172318357
10-24 21:10:58.677: I/Web Console(19755): Position updated: latitude=50.646238333333336, longitude=-4.736944716666667, accuracy=9m at :1172318357
10-24 21:10:59.747: I/Web Console(19755): Position updated: latitude=50.6462348, longitude=-4.736952216666666, accuracy=9m at :1172318357
10-24 21:11:00.667: I/Web Console(19755): Position updated: latitude=50.64623206666667, longitude=-4.73695695, accuracy=9m at :1172318357
10-24 21:11:01.677: I/Web Console(19755): Position updated: latitude=50.646232700000006, longitude=-4.7369544999999995, accuracy=9m at :1172318357
10-24 21:11:02.677: I/Web Console(19755): Position updated: latitude=50.646232700000006, longitude=-4.7369544999999995, accuracy=12m at :1172318357
10-24 21:11:03.687: I/Web Console(19755): Position updated: latitude=50.64623241666666, longitude=-4.736952116666667, accuracy=12m at :1172318357
10-24 21:11:04.207: I/Web Console(19755): Position updated: latitude=50.646240533333334, longitude=-4.736951266666667, accuracy=12m at :1172318357
10-24 21:11:05.187: I/Web Console(19755): Position updated: latitude=50.646235399999995, longitude=-4.736953183333334, accuracy=12m at :1172318357
10-24 21:11:06.197: I/Web Console(19755): Position updated: latitude=50.6462522, longitude=-4.736926933333334, accuracy=12m at :1172318357
10-24 21:11:07.197: I/Web Console(19755): Position updated: latitude=50.646253949999995, longitude=-4.736931416666667, accuracy=12m at :1172318357
10-24 21:11:07.517: I/Web Console(19755): Position update rejected because accuracy of45m is less than required 20m at :1172318357
10-24 21:11:08.197: I/Web Console(19755): Position updated: latitude=50.64624196666667, longitude=-4.736951366666666, accuracy=9m at :1172318357
10-24 21:11:09.697: I/Web Console(19755): Position updated: latitude=50.646261833333334, longitude=-4.73694825, accuracy=9m at :1172318357
10-24 21:11:10.697: I/Web Console(19755): Position updated: latitude=50.64627816666666, longitude=-4.736968816666666, accuracy=9m at :1172318357
10-24 21:11:11.197: I/Web Console(19755): Position updated: latitude=50.64627698333334, longitude=-4.736982066666667, accuracy=9m at :1172318357
10-24 21:11:12.197: I/Web Console(19755): Position updated: latitude=50.646291033333334, longitude=-4.736992866666667, accuracy=9m at :1172318357
10-24 21:11:13.197: I/Web Console(19755): Position updated: latitude=50.646285549999995, longitude=-4.73696835, accuracy=9m at :1172318357
10-24 21:11:14.197: I/Web Console(19755): Position updated: latitude=50.64628801666666, longitude=-4.736988766666667, accuracy=9m at :1172318357
10-24 21:11:15.197: I/Web Console(19755): Position updated: latitude=50.646256433333335, longitude=-4.736974683333333, accuracy=9m at :1172318357
10-24 21:11:16.197: I/Web Console(19755): Position updated: latitude=50.64623895, longitude=-4.736980716666666, accuracy=9m at :1172318357
10-24 21:11:17.207: I/Web Console(19755): Position updated: latitude=50.646249616666665, longitude=-4.736948533333333, accuracy=9m at :1172318357
10-24 21:11:18.207: I/Web Console(19755): Position updated: latitude=50.64624111666667, longitude=-4.7369412833333335, accuracy=9m at :1172318357
10-24 21:11:19.217: I/Web Console(19755): Position updated: latitude=50.64624506666667, longitude=-4.7369719, accuracy=9m at :1172318357
10-24 21:11:20.207: I/Web Console(19755): Position updated: latitude=50.646218950000005, longitude=-4.7369769999999995, accuracy=9m at :1172318357
10-24 21:11:21.207: I/Web Console(19755): Position updated: latitude=50.64621395000001, longitude=-4.7369834, accuracy=9m at :1172318357
10-24 21:11:22.207: I/Web Console(19755): Position updated: latitude=50.646217416666666, longitude=-4.736986783333333, accuracy=12m at :1172318357
10-24 21:11:23.207: I/Web Console(19755): Position updated: latitude=50.646211816666664, longitude=-4.7369768500000005, accuracy=12m at :1172318357
10-24 21:11:24.707: I/Web Console(19755): Position updated: latitude=50.646210450000005, longitude=-4.736994233333333, accuracy=12m at :1172318357
10-24 21:11:25.707: I/Web Console(19755): Position updated: latitude=50.64621571666667, longitude=-4.736988583333333, accuracy=12m at :1172318357
10-24 21:11:26.707: I/Web Console(19755): Position updated: latitude=50.646216466666665, longitude=-4.7370037, accuracy=12m at :1172318357
10-24 21:11:27.707: I/Web Console(19755): Position updated: latitude=50.64621723333333, longitude=-4.737019266666667, accuracy=20m at :1172318357
10-24 21:11:28.717: I/Web Console(19755): Position updated: latitude=50.64621738333334, longitude=-4.737011333333333, accuracy=12m at :1172318357
10-24 21:11:29.717: I/Web Console(19755): Position updated: latitude=50.64621768333333, longitude=-4.7370187, accuracy=18m at :1172318357
10-24 21:11:30.727: I/Web Console(19755): Position updated: latitude=50.64621798333333, longitude=-4.737026116666667, accuracy=18m at :1172318357
```

Comment: Thanks for the help with accuracy and resetting the watch, but I still have one first good position, and then the icon disappears and the location is not updated.

Comment: Thanks for the code.When I test on my device, I get the same error code 3 : timed out without getting any gps location. Even with 30000ms, I still get time out errors.

I managed to make it work on my app using your trick to restart the watcher when I get errors. So what's happening is : 

1- The watcher is launched.
2- A Position is found, I get the gps location.
3- An error is thrown : The code 3 timed out.
4- As you told me, I clear the watcher, then launch it again
- restarts at step 1 ...

This is working, but the behavior is strange.

Comment: I noticed that when I launch my app, and then I launch google maps over it, google maps has the gps icon not blinking, and my position is updated very quickly when I move. The logcat tells me that my app in background is receiving the gps locations, because google maps uses it ! This is crazy.

Comment: You're right, I'm seeing exactly the same behaviour with 3.1.0 but not with 2.9.0

Comment: Did you end up finding a solution?
I'm having exactly the same issue.

Comment: @grim No, I haven't found a solution. I've kept my apps using 2.9.0 for now. When the next major phonegap version is released, I will try it against this test case and see if the problem has been fixed. Sorry I can't be of further help :-(

Comment: @Dpa99c I ended up downgrading to 2.9.0. This is very frustrating as I have just updated from that version and I was so excited to do so. I'd expect more from Phonegap/Adobe; a feature that important should be tested before a release. Even using Phonegap 3.1.0, the geolocation doesn't work.

Comment: I'm gonna try with the 2.9.0 too, I keep you posted with my results.

Comment: @Dpa99c Look at my answer, i found a solution.

Comment: @grim Look at my answer, i found a solution.

Answer (score 0):

I did solve the problem adding this line to manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

By default, CLI commands does not add this line to manifest.

You must give permission to the app to get the position using wifi and cellphone antennas

I was testing using this line but there was no difference:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS" />
```

I already changed the time to get new position in file GPSListener.java located in app/src/org.apache.cordova.geolocation at this line:

```
this.locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 60000, 0, this);
```

I did changed 60000 for 2000, but there was no difference.

My Device is i9300 with Android 4.3

I hope this info can help somebody!

Greetings!

Answer (score 0):

First make sure that your code is bug free  ! 
If you are sure then you need to do one more thing ! 
Just change the security settings of your Android device.
Go to Settings -> Security -> Check the "Unknown sources" checkbox
in order to allow your apk to be run without any problem.

Hope it works as it did for me !